# Getting the list of arguments passed to a method in unix

Tags: shell, unix, hp-ux

I have a shell script that is calling another script passing some **variable** number of arguments.

One of the argument(**dont know the position of the argument**) will be name "**temp**".

In another script,i need to test if any of the argument recieved is "test" from the list of arguments and do some calculations based on that.

I know that $1 is the first argument, $@ is all of them and all function parameters can be access via $1,$2..$N.

I need a way so that i can get all the arguments in an Array or something and then i can check in that array whether "**temp**" is present or not.

I am new to UNIX and i dont know how to implement this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use $* to get all the params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ?...

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $(echo $* | grep -c temp) -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "not found"
else
  echo "found"
fi
```

Comment: `if echo "$*" | grep -q temp` is simpler.